# How to push git push options without creating a new commit?

Tags: git

I want to use git [push options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push/2.35.0#Documentation/git-push.txt---push-optionltoptiongt) without having to create a new commit or amend and push force the previous commit. How can I do that? E.g. something like:

```bash
git commit -m "Something"
git push

# a bit later, when I realize I want to create an MR:
git push -o merge_request.create
```

Currently this doesn't work, and the output is:

```
You are connecting to my-git-host.com
Everything up-to-date
```

`merge_request.create` is GitLab specific, but it could have been any push option I wanted to push after I have already pushed the commits.

Comment: "*I want to push without pushing a commit*" Then what do you suppose to push? Git can only push commits and references (branches and tags).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It was not that obvious to me, e.g. you can push commands like `git push --delete origin some-ref`. Or does this count like pushing a reference (but that is also strange, the ref is never precent locally, I only edit remote refs)? Pushing push options with delete commands does not work, but since it was possible to push commands like that I thought it maybe was possible to apply push options without pushing commits or refs

Comment: Ah, nice, here you beat me! :-))) Well, let's me learn that Git can only push commits, references and reference deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As phd says in their comment, you can't apply push options if you're not pushing something. The simplest option may be amend your latest commit without making any changes; that is, run:

```
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

This will change the date on your commit which will generate a new commit id. Now you can force push an update with your desired push options:

```
git push -f -o merge_request.create
```

---

Alternately, you could roll back the remote repository by one commit. Assuming that you're working with the `main` branch, that would be:

```
git push -f origin HEAD^:main
```

Now you can push the most recent commit with your desired push options because your local repository is one commit ahead of the remote:

```
git push -o merge_request.create
```

This has the advantage of preserving your commit ids, at the expense of additional steps.